# Append datatables success but thead section gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm try to use `append` to fill my table. Please take a look

```
<table width="100%" id="tbltbl" class="asoy table table-bordered table-striped">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                <th width="1%">No</th>
                 <th width="14%">Outlet</th>
                 <th width="14%">Leader</th>
                 <th width="14%">Chief</th>
                 <th width="14%">RM</th>
                  <th> Action </th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
   </table>
```

for default my table look like this
[image]
I run the `onchange` method and i receive this

```
[{"OutletCode":"K-BDIP3","Description":"BANDUNG INDAH PLAZA 3","NipLeader":"0802400","NipRM":"0802678"
,"NipChief":"-"},{"OutletCode":"K-CMHM2","Description":"KIOS CIMAHI MALL 2","NipLeader":"0802400","NipRM"
:"0802678","NipChief":"-"},{"OutletCode":"K-TSPA3","Description":"TASIK PLAZA ASIA 3","NipLeader":"0802400"
,"NipRM":"0802678","NipChief":"-"},{"OutletCode":"K-BDCW2","Description":"KIOS BANDUNG CIWALK 2","NipLeader"
:"0802400","NipRM":"0802678","NipChief":"-"}]
```

then i append it

```
function byarea(){
        $(".asoy").empty();
        var area = $("#pilihanarea").val();
        var tipe = $('#tipe').val();
        var formUrl = "<?=base_url();?>arealeader/finddata";
        var angka = 1;
            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                 data: {tipe:tipe,area:area},
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    var newdata = JSON.parse(data);
                     $.each(newdata, function(key, val) {
                        $('.asoy').append('<tbody><tr> <td>'+ (angka++) +'</td>' + 
                                            '<td>' + val.OutletCode + '</td>' + 
                                            '<td>' + val.NipLeader + '</td>' + 
                                            '<td>' + val.NipChief +'</td>' + 
                                            '<td>' + val.NipRM +'</td>' + 
                                            '<td>----</td>' + 
                                            '</tr></tbody></thead>');
                        });
                }
            });
    }
```

and my table look like this

[image]

It seems I'm loosing my `<thead>..</thead>` section. Any solution for this ? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty `<tbody class="asoy"></tbody>` just before the closing `</table>` tag and remove the class "asoy" from the `<table>` tag. Then remove the `<tbody>` tags from your call to `append()`.

At the moment, your `$(".asoy").empty();` is removing the entire table contents but you only want to clear the body, not the headers. Creating a `<tbody>` tag solves that problem while still allowing your function to be re-entrant (i.e. you can run it again later and it won't duplicate the contents).

Comment: jQuery datatables have a better way to load data. You should read documentation/examples on loading for datatables in particular, which will preserve its functionality including sorting. Perhaps amend your question to ask what the datatables-native way would be to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your code

```
 $('.asoy').append('<tbody>
                           <tr> <td>'+ (angka++) +'</td>' + 
                               '<td>' + val.OutletCode + '</td>' + 
                               '<td>' + val.NipLeader + '</td>' + 
                               '<td>' + val.NipChief +'</td>' + 
                               '<td>' + val.NipRM +'</td>' + 
                                '<td>----</td>' + 
                               '</tr>
                     </tbody>
                     </thead>'); // <--- What this tag for? 
                                      I'm not sure but I think its a wrong tagging. 
                                      tbody should not be inside a thead unless your 
                                      header will consist of another table element
```

Comment: The `</thead>` shouldn't be there but that's not the cause of the issue.